# alias name in brocade

Tags: storage, storage-area-network, switch

how do i look for alias name using the WWN in brocade.
Say i have created an alias "CentosNode2Port1"
using switch show i get the WWN ,but how to look for the alias name.

> alishow (WWN) is not accepting.

please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is going to sound rude but don't you think it's time that you went on a Brocade course, bought a book or looked on Brocade's website for their command reference?

90%> of your queries are one-to-three clicks away from a google search - there's only ever me answering your questions (and I'm more of a Cisco MDS guy myself) - I just think you should take control of this work you have to do - get on a training course, tell you managers you need it - buy that book, get digging into Brocade's site. It's not that I don't want to help I just think you're not trying to help yourself.

**Update**

Literally 1 click from a google search ("brocade search alias wwn") gets me [THIS](http://storagesupport.wordpress.com/2009/07/14/searching-ns-entries-or-name-server-for-wwn-fcid-or-alias-name/).

===cut from article===

When you want to search a wwn or fcid or alias name of entire fabric:

> nsallshow | grep “wwn / fcid / aliasname”

When you want search in all switches except the switch from where you enter the command:

> nscamshow | grep ” wwn / fcid / aliasname”

When you want to search in local switch alone:

> nsshow | grep ” wwn / fcid / aliasname”

===end of cut===

Hopefully that might help - oh and you owe me extra details in question 146648

Comment: seriously , i am not finding it..even after googling

Comment: thanks chopper for you help..i am doing my best to learn things.
i will put some more effort this time b'fore coming here for doubts..Thanks for a prompt reply!
I will get back to that question later (146648) in case i don't find it after trying..

Comment: nodefind <wwn>  is what i was looking for

Answer (score -1):

nodefind 10:00:00:00:c9:ab:cd:ef

Last line of output of this command will show the aliasnames it is associated with.

It will check the complete connected fabric.

Comment: How can that *POSSIBLY* work for this user when he's not provided WWN details? That may well work for your setup but please read our help pages so you understand what this site is for and what it isn't